# Cannot link with OpenSSL crypto library when compiling OpenSSH (PKIXSSH) on AIX

Tags: openssl, aix, openssh

I am trying to compile [pkixssh](https://roumenpetrov.info/secsh/) (a fork of OpenSSH) on AIX using a compiled version also of OpenSSL without success.

The error shown in the configure phase is the following:

```
checking how to link programs using OpenSSL functions... fail
configure: error: cannot link with OpenSSL crypto library
```

OpenSSH 1.1.1d has been succesfully compiled under /soft/openssh-8.1, so the librairies are under /soft/openssh-8.1/lib

```
$ ls /soft/openssh-8.1/lib
engines-1.1         libcrypto.so        libcrypto64.so.1.1  libssl.a            libssl.so.1         libssl_a.a
libcrypto.a         libcrypto.so.1      libcrypto_a.a       libssl.so           libssl64.so.1.1     pkgconfig
```

and are correctly found for the openssl binary, by example:

```
$ ldd /soft/openssh-8.1/bin/openssl
/soft/openssh-8.1/bin/openssl needs:
         /soft/openssh-8.1/lib/libssl.a(libssl64.so.1.1)
         /soft/openssh-8.1/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto64.so.1.1)
         /opt/freeware/lib/libz.so
         /usr/ccs/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)
         /usr/ccs/lib/libc.a(shr_64.o)
         /unix
         /soft/openssh-8.1/lib/libcrypt.a(shr_64.o)
```

I had tested with different combinations of LDFLAGS, but without success.

AIX version is 7.1 on powerpc
GCC version is 4.6.1

The configure command run to configure OpenSSH's compilation is the following:

```
./configure --prefix=/soft/openssh-8.1/                                 \
        --sbindir=/soft/openssh-8.1/bin                                 \
        --sysconfdir=/soft/openssh-8.1/data                             \
        --datadir=/soft/openssh-8.1/data                                \
        --with-pid-dir=/soft/openssh-8.1/data                           \
        --without-stackprotect                                          \
        --with-pam                                                      \
        --with-md5-passwords                                            \
        --with-ssl-dir=/soft/openssh-8.1                                \
        --with-privsep-path=/var/empty/sshd
```

Any idea?

Comment: Now is it openssh-8.1 or pkixssh-12.3 what you try to compile? If the latter, did you use configure-option `--with-ssl-dir=/soft/openssh-8.1/`?

Comment: Hi! It's pkixssh-12.3. And we are using already that option. We have almost finished the compilation.In short I will answer my own question :-)

Answer (score 0):

The key for compiling on AIX is using the variable **LIBPATH**, equivalent to LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Linux.

In this case in particular the variable **blibpath** was set also, as is used in the configure scripts to pass the custom library paths as options to the compiler and set this paths as library search path in the binaries.

To be sure that 64 bits binaries are used in the compilation the following variables where set before the configure command:

```
OPENSSH_PATH="/soft/openssh-8.1"
export PATH="/soft/perl-5.16.3/bin:$OPENSSH_PATH/bin:$PATH"
# Library path in linking time
export blibpath="$OPENSSH_PATH/lib:/opt/freeware/lib64:/usr/lib:/lib"
# Library path in run time
export LIBPATH="$OPENSSH_PATH/lib:/opt/freeware/lib64:/opt/freeware/lib:/opt/lib64:/opt/64/lib:/opt/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib:/lib:/usr/ccs/lib/"
export CFLAGS="-g -O2"
export CC="gcc -maix64"
export OBJECT_MODE=64
export NM="nm -X64"
export AR="ar -X64"
```

As said, the two main variables to set are **blibpath** used in the compilation phase and **LIBPATH** used when running the binaries.

The result binaries have the libraires correctly set :-)

```
$ ldd /soft/openssh-8.1/bin/sshd
/soft/openssh-8.1/bin/sshd needs:
     /usr/lib/libc.a(shr_64.o)
     /soft/openssh-8.1/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto64.so.1.1)
     /soft/openssh-8.1/lib/libssl.a(libssl64.so.1.1)
     /usr/lib/libz.a(libz.so.1)
     /usr/lib/libpam.a(shr_64.o)
     /unix
     /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr_64.o)
     /opt/freeware/lib64/libz.so
     /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libmls.a(shr_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libmlsenc.a(shr_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libodm.a(shr_64.o)

$ dump -X64 -Hv /soft/openssh-8.1/bin/sshd

/soft/openssh-8.1/bin/sshd:

                        ***Loader Section***
                      Loader Header Information
VERSION#         #SYMtableENT     #RELOCent        LENidSTR
0x00000001       0x00000247       0x00000734       0x000000aa

#IMPfilID        OFFidSTR         LENstrTBL        OFFstrTBL
0x00000006       0x0000aa20       0x0000238a       0x0000aaca


                        ***Import File Strings***
INDEX  PATH                          BASE                MEMBER
0      /soft/openssh-8.1/lib:/opt/freeware/lib64:/usr/lib:/lib
1                                    libc.a              shr_64.o
2                                    libcrypto.a         libcrypto64.so.1.1
3                                    libssl.a            libssl64.so.1.1
4                                    libz.a              libz.so.1
5                                    libpam.a            shr_64.o
```

```
$ ldd /soft/openssh-8.1/libexec/sftp-server
/soft/openssh-8.1/libexec/sftp-server needs:
     /usr/lib/libc.a(shr_64.o)
     /soft/openssh-8.1/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto64.so.1.1)
     /unix
     /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr_64.o)
     /opt/freeware/lib64/libz.so
     /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)

$ dump -X64 -Hv /soft/openssh-8.1/libexec/sftp-server

/soft/openssh-8.1/libexec/sftp-server:

                        ***Loader Section***
                      Loader Header Information
VERSION#         #SYMtableENT     #RELOCent        LENidSTR
0x00000001       0x00000081       0x0000016b       0x0000006b

#IMPfilID        OFFidSTR         LENstrTBL        OFFstrTBL
0x00000003       0x00002300       0x00000552       0x0000236b


                        ***Import File Strings***
INDEX  PATH                          BASE                MEMBER
0      /soft/openssh-8.1/lib:/opt/freeware/lib64:/usr/lib:/lib
1                                    libc.a              shr_64.o
2                                    libcrypto.a         libcrypto64.so.1.1
```

The `ldd` command tells what librairies are used and the `dump -X64 -Hv` tells in what paths this librairies are going to be used.

Comment: A good post with compilation notes for AIX is at http://www.hpc.cineca.it/content/tips-linking-libraries-ibm-sp6-aix